# How to get all the views in a dialog?

Tags: android, listview, dialog, android-alertdialog

In my case i have 15 elements in dialog. By

```
dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                ListView list = dialog.getListView();

                list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                        view.setText( ((AppCompatCheckedTextView) v).getText() );
                        view.setFocusable( false );
                        dialog.dismiss();

                    }
                });
```

method using **dialog.getListView()** i get 10 elements which displayed in dialog window.

```
for (int i = 1; i < list.getCount(); i++) {
    if (Integer.valueOf(array[i]) > Integer.valueOf(sumInsured)) {
        AppCompatCheckedTextView view = (AppCompatCheckedTextView) list.getChildAt(i);
        //Disable on click listener so that checkbox is not activated.
        view.setOnClickListener(null);
        //Disable the view.
        view.setEnabled(false);
    }
 }
```

By the above code I could able to disable last four elements (7-10). On scroll accessing 11th element (visible) i get null pointer exception. How to access views which are not displayed to dialog window. I want make disable that views also....